# MySQL join only latest row

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables with following column names:

restaurants:

- id, name, cuisine, address, image_file

reviews:

- id, restaurant_id(foreign key), user_id(foreign key), header, content, posted_at, modified_at

users: -id, username, email, password, privileges

In my PHP project on the main page where i want to display all the restaurants with the latest review if there is any review. Can someone please help me how to do that within single query and single foreach loop? I've tried left join with subqueries but could not resolve the problem of duplicated rows. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
  FROM restaurants
  LEFT JOIN
     (
       SELECT restaurant_id AS restId, MAX(posted_at) AS lastTime
         FROM reviews
        GROUP BY restaurant_id
     ) AS last_reviews
    ON last_reviews.restId = restaurants.id
  LEFT JOIN reviews
    ON reviews.posted_at = last_reviews.lastTime
   AND reviews.restaurant_id = restaurants.id
```

Comment: Thanks Svyatoslav, its working! One small detail, how to fetch all columns, not just id and name? somehow with *

Comment: @user19610670 is this a *small detail*?

Comment: I corrected answer

Comment: Seems like, im pretty new to joining tables. do you think the problem is in GROUP BY?

Comment: Yes, you should grouping tables by the right attributes for getting results without duplicates. Or, for example, sort by desc and get limit 1

Comment: I tried the updated one but its not fetching the restaurants with 0 reviews and restaurants are duplicated

Comment: user19610670  and now?